# Determine whether Set is closed,whether it is open, whether it is bounded and whether it is compact

Tags: general-topology

#### Question:

Given the
$$f(x,y)=y-\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$$
consider the set $S = \{(x,y) \in D: x > 0,\ f(x,y) > 0\}$ where $D$ is the domain of $f$.
Sketch the set $S$ in the plane. Determine whether $S$ is closed,whether it is open, whether it is bounded and whether it is compact. Explain carefully

---

#### Attempt at answer:

The domain will be $x>0$ and $y>\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$

A function is closed if it contains all of its boundary points

I’m not sure if I am correct in saying but since it is not a strictly greater than and equal than it does not include all of the boundary points
Also $(1,1)$ is a boundary point in $S$ but it is not an element of the set as $1=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1^2}$

A function is open if all points are interior points. Not to sure how to show this one?

A function is bounded if you can draw a ball of radius $k$ such that the entire set is contained
This is not possible as the function is infinite so will always have points outside the ball

A function is compact if it is closed and bounded. Since it is neither closed nor bounded it is not compact.

Comment: For $x<0$ the function is defined. Why the restriction $x>0$ when you are talking about its domain?

Comment: the question just asked to consider x>0    or am I confusing it?

Comment: $D$ was referred to as the *domain* of $f$ and I do not see restrictions on it. $S$ was defined on base of $D$ with extra conditions among which $x>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me go through your attempted answer:

> The domain will be $x>0$ and $y>\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$

If you meant to say that $S=\{(x,y); x>0, y>\frac1{x^2}\}$, then this is correct.

If you meant $D$ by the word *domain*, then this is incorrect: $D$ is the set of all points for which $f(x,y)$ is defined.

> A function is closed if it contains all of its boundary points

You meant to say that a *set* (not a *function) is closed if and only if it contains all boundary points. (But this is probably just a typo.)

> Also $(1,1)$ is a boundary point in $S$ but it is not an element of the set as $1=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1^2}$

Yes, this is true. But maybe you should also explain why $(1,1)$ is a boundary point.

> A function is open if all points are interior points. Not to sure how to show this one?

If you have $(x,y)\in S$ then
$$y>\frac1{x^2}$$
and $x>0$.

Using continuity of the function $g(x)=1/x^2$ (or maybe using $h(x)=\frac1{x^2}-x$ would be even simpler), can you show that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that 
$$ |s-x|<\varepsilon, |t-y|<\varepsilon \qquad \implies \qquad s>\frac1{t^2}?$$
This basically says that points close enough to $(x,y)\in S$ are still in $S$. Showing this is sufficient to get that each $(x,y)\in S$ is an interior point.

> A function is bounded if you can draw a ball of radius $k$ such that the entire set is contained

You should write *set* instead of *function*.

> This is not possible as the function is infinite so will always have points outside the ball.

I get your point, but perhaps you should explain it more in detail. For example the points $P_n=(n,n)$ for $n>1$ all belong to $S$. Is it clear that for any ball $B(0,r)$ around the origin one of this points will be outside the given ball?

> A function is compact if it is closed and bounded. Since it is neither closed nor bounded it is not compact.

Again *set* instead of *function*. Otherwise ok.

Comment: $P_n \in S$ if $n > 1$

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help

Comment: @drhab Thanks I have corrected it.

Comment: @DarthGeek Thanks I have corrected this.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain why (1,1) is a boundary point.

Comment: also i showing that is open I understand your summary but I dont understand the first part of it and where you get the equations from eg the f(x) and g(x)

Comment: @erin That depends on your definition of boundary point. If your definition is that $P$ is a boundary point of $S$ if and only if any neighborhood of $P$ contains points both from the set $S$ and its complement $S$, then you could simply try to show that you can find such points close to $(1,1)$. For example $(1+\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ and $(1-\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon)$. Or you might say that existence of such points is clear from the picture. (It all depends on how rigorously do you want/are supposed to write the proof.)

Comment: @erin I have changed notation to $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. (It was my mistake - I should not have used $f$, since another function is already denoted by $f$.) I have suggested $h(x)=\frac1{x^2}-x$ because $(x,y)\in S$ $\leftrightarrow$ $x>0$ and $y>h(x)$.

Comment: yes that is the definition that we are using for boundary pt. this is probably a stupid question but why do the two values have to be the same eg (1+e,1+e)

Comment: @erin They don't have to be the same. I have simply used the same values, because from the picture it is obvious that one of them is in $S$ and the other isn't. You can as well take $(1,1+\varepsilon)$ and $(1,1-\varepsilon)$. (This might be even better when doing the computation showing whether the point is in $S$.) I should have also written that $\varepsilon>0$, but this is probably clear from the context.

Comment: Thanks that has cleared it up a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is the domain of $f$ **restricted** to $S$. The actual domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,y): y\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

As you said, $(1,1)$ is a boundary point of $S$ that doesn't belong in $S$ so $S$ is not closed.

To show that all it's points are interior, consider this:

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in S$ then $x_0 > 0$ and $x_0^2y_0 > 1$. Let $d = \min\lbrace\sqrt{(x_0-x)^2+(y_0-y)^2}:x^2y=1\rbrace$
Consider $k = \min\{x_0,d\}$

Then $B\left((x_0,y_0),k\right)\subseteq S$. Therefore all points in $S$ are interior.

Your proof that $S$ is not bounded seems a bit dodgy. Perhaps this helps. $c:=(1,2)\in S$. So if $S$ is bounded there is a $k\in R$ so that $S \subseteq B(c,k)$ But $(2k+1,2)\in S$ while $(2k+1,2)\notin B(c,k)$. Therefore, $S$ is not bounded.

Indeed, if $S$ is not closed or not bounded it is not compact.